# Programmatically login customer is not working with Associate to Website as “Main website"

Tags: login, programmatically

I am trying to login a customer using email id and password.
Please check my below code:

```
public function customerlogin($email,$password)
 {
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
    try
    {
        $session->login($email,$password);
        $session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn( $session->getCustomer() );
        return json_encode(array('status' => 'success'));
    }
    catch( Exception $e )
    {
        return json_encode(array('status' => 'error'));
    }
}
```

Suppose I have two customers. One of them is created as “Associate to Website” as “Admin”. And other one is created as “Associate to Website” as “Main website”

Now if I passed username and password of customer who associate with admin then I am getting success in response. But if I try to pass username and password of “Main website” customer then I always get an error in response.
Why this is happening?

I am passing correct username and password.

Comment: The best way to debug is to findout what error message you are getting, try `json_encode(array('status' => 'error', 'msg' => $e->getMessage()));` or in your dev environment `Mage::logException($e);`

Comment: I tried this.I am getting message "Invalid login or password." But I am passing correct email id and password. I just do a little bit debug about this.I am not getting "PasswordHash" from customer model.

Comment: @MilopleInc any solutions about that please?